# PHP substr of hex

Tags: php, hex

Is it possible to get a subsection of a hex value? For example:

```
0x7dd becomes 0xdd
```

Or even to get a subsection of binary value. For example:

```
$hex = 0x7dd;    
$bin = hex2bin($hex);
$ bin = substr($bin,4); //so it excludes the four most significant bits ie. the most significant hex digit
```

Does anybody know of a efficient way of oing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a bitmask in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880360/how-to-implement-a-bitmask-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read on [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Applying `&` (bitwise and) on a mask, or `>>` (right-shift) could be what your looking for (without converting back and forth to `string`).

For example:

```
0x7dd & 0xff == 0xdd
```

where `& 0xff` essentially ignores everything except the last two hex digits

Comment: The "&" operator is what I was looking for, my encryption algorithm now works perfectly.